# Faster way to Refactoring code

Tags: java

bg:Now I want to divide project A into Project B and Project C.

For project B, there must be some classes like this

```
public class Example{
   public void methodForProjectB(){
   ///   
   }

   public void methodForProjectC(){
   ///
   }

}
```

So as I want to delete methodForProjectC() in projectB, it cost me a lot of times to know if a method is called, is there any faster way?

Also, if I can know the dependcy of every class **clearly**, then it would be easier to know
 which class is not needed anymore.

Comment: A good IDE will allow you to find usages, this will show you where the method is being used. In the worst case scenario delete the method and see if the code compiles...

Comment: using eclipse there is an option to find references of method/field in all project.

Comment: Yes, delete method is a way, but it's not fast, 100 method need 100 times, it is not a high efficiency way. how to set eclipse to work this?

Comment: Any of the big three will work; Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Eclipse plugin called [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) which can detect unnecessary code. It analyses your entire codebase, and finds all methods and classes which do not appear to be used.

We regularly use this on our codebase, and it works well. Our main problem is that we build some of our application code into libraries, and export it to other applications. UCDetector doesn't know about those applications, so it can't detect their uses of the code. This problem is very much due to our haphazard packaging and reuse strategy, and not any shortcoming in UCDetector.

Answer (score 2):

A good IDE handles this pretty well:

Here are some options:

Eclipse  -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> Find all usages of a function in the workspace.

Neteans  -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> -> Find usage

I'm sure that other IDEs have similar features, which save a lot of time (and headackes).

Comment: I test Ctrl+G in eclipse, it can find List matches java.util and java.awt, but it can't find class who ever used ClassA.method(), do you really understand what do I mean Or it's just because my operation  is wrong？

Comment: My bad, just click on your method and press ctrl+shift+G :) Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a good IDE with refactoring support built-in.  I believe IntelliJ from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) is the best IDE on the market.  I'd recommend either trying the community edition or investing in a licensed copy.

Comment: "The best IDE" is a matter of taste. While IntelliJ is a really good IDE in my opinion, I prefer Eclipse. There are also some people who have Netbeans as their favorite.

Comment: Nope, just a very satisfied customer.  I think it's clear that this is an opinion, not intended to be definitive.  I can speak from authority after using Eclipse for five years prior to finding IntelliJ.  I've never gone back.

Comment: Aren't there better venues for discussing the relative merits of IDEs?

Comment: Where would you recommend?  Why are you asking me?  I'm just answering the question.